# Including a parameter in a column alias as part of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in my stored proc that returns the number of events in which a horse has been awarded first place. I pass the place as a default parameter like this:

```
`@place AS tinyint = 1`
```

I would like to include this in my column which will show the number of wins titled `'Number of wins where place = ' + @place`. What is the solution?

I tried

```
SELECT horse_name, COUNT(event_id) AS CONCAT('number of wins', ' where place = ', @place)
```

but it says:

> incorrect syntax near 'number of wins' expecting '(' or SELECT

Comment: The short answer is that object names, column names, aliases. et.al. cannot be expressions, parameterized or not.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I removed the parameter from the alias.

Comment: Only way to do that is by using dynamic sql.

Comment: Could you elaborate? @ZoharPeled

Comment: See Eduardo Garcia's answer.

Comment: Just include the place in a separate column.  Don't change the name of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dynamic Sql

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = ''

SET @SQL = N'SELECT horse_name, COUNT(event_id) AS '  + CONCAT('number of wins', ' where place = ', CAST(@place AS nvarchar(4))) +
N'FROM your_table'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Ok, so the only way is with dynamic SQL which makes it a bit tricky to write. I think it's not worth the effort in this case but now I understand how it can be achieved.

Comment: Careful, this is very open to injection. You need to be properly quoting your objects, @DmitriTrosenko . This'll be next to impossible bwith a `varchar(4)` but still should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT horse_name, COUNT(event_id) AS 'number of wins ' + cast(@place as varchar(8))
```

Comment: @DmitriTrotsenko Please let me the know the error message you are getting as I tested in on SQL Server and it works for me.

Comment: SQL80001: incorrect syntax near '+', @place and '8'

Comment: Try using a number, say 5 in place of the variable <place>. If that works that the value of <place> is not being set. If that does not work then I do not have any more solutions. It works for me using sqlcmd with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You want parameter value in column for that try below script.

```
SELECT horse_name, COUNT(event_id) AS 'number of wins where place = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @place)
```